# Subversion Edge gives: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Tags: subversion-edge

I installed CollabNet Subversion Edge Version 6.0.2 on a Windows Server 2019. The most runs fine.

But from time to time when I open http://myserver:3343 (the csvn login page) the browser shows default html elements. And if I then do my login I get: HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Full error message:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Error 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 
'/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 
'/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'</h2>
<table>
<tbody><tr><th>URI:</th><td>/csvn/login/authenticate</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 
'/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>grailsDispatcherServlet</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>javax.servlet.ServletException: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 
'/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    ... 23 more
</pre>



</body></html>
```

I thougth I got the cause before some weeks when I arranged the backup schedules new. Before I've started them all at the same time. Now every 5 min a new backup is started. It was better but today I got the error again. May I have to increase the 5 min.

Does someone have similar experiences or better solutions?

Thanks